# Explicit and safe git pull in Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is it possible to do "git pull" safely in Intellij IDEA 9?

Now I am using Git -> Pull Changes... and then **I have to select branch explicitly** - this is source of error if I pull from not current branch by error. This is completely unsafe. I wonder if there is a safer way to do "git pull" in IDEA through standard UI.

Use `git pull` in command line is not a good option, because we have IDE to increase productivity and convenience and part of functions is already implemented well for git.

Another major case is when you want to pull changes from tracking branch. For example your have created `newfeature` branch from master on local master and want to update it from master.

Comment: Totally agree that this is dangerous... and still not fixed in IDEA 10.0.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vladimir, you may use the Update Project action. 
It performs git pull for the tracked branch.

Comment: Wow @LoKi, I wait for this answer so long. Didn't realize that it can resize outside the "Git" menu. Now it will be so easy to do. Thanks so much!

Comment: LoKi - Is there a reason why I can't do a simple "git pull" in IntelliJ?  When I do Update Project in IntelliJ, it does 'git fetch --prune origin' followed by 'git rev-list -1 master..origin/master' which I guess works fine, but again, I don't understand why I can't simply do a 'git pull' from inside IntelliJ.

Comment: @JunhoPark Update Project == `git fetch origin ; git merge origin/master` == `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use an external Git client for such tasks and the internal one for compare or commit tasks.

Comment: command line or external git client is not an option because Intellij IDEA is considered to have a set of all important daily features for git.

Comment: You can download the source code of IDEA and do the necessary changes yourself to make its Git integration "right". If the Jetbrains people think it is worth to apply your patch, then they will do it.

Comment: I posted this question to JetBrains - will wait to hear from them.